# Права пользователя в linux

Tags: linux, git, chown

Использую git для обновления рабочей версии сайта из репозитория на том же сервере. Папки-файлы сайтов принадлежат пользователю А, git же работает через пользователя B.

При попытке обновить файлы сайта git ругается, что нет прав.

Можно ли как то централизованно дать права пользователю B за работу с файлами сайтов? Или надо для каждой папки с сайтом отдельно выставлять права?

Структура такова:

```
/var/www/user/data/www/site1.ru
/var/www/user/data/www/site2.ru
/var/www/user/data/www/siteN.ru
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую рассказать о группах и правах. В комментарий не влезло...

Нет, в *nix у самой по себе группы (а также и у пользователя) никаких прав нет. Права есть у *файла*.

К файлу приписаны пользователь и группа. А пользователь в свою очередь приписан к одной или нескольким группам.

Посмотрите на

```
avp@avp-xub11:~$ ls -l /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 83972 Mar 19 14:39 /var/log/syslog
avp@avp-xub11:~$
```

Вот эти -rw-r----- -- это права (если кратко и не до конца полно -- r - чтение, w - запись, х - запуск файла на исполнение) user-а (в данном случае syslog -- rw-), group (adm r--) и всех прочих (---) на действия с файлом `/var/log/syslog`.

Команда id

```
avp@avp-xub11:~$ id
uid=1000(avp) gid=1000(avp) groups=1000(avp),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),46(plugdev),117(lpadmin),119(admin),124(sambashare),1001(vboxsf)
avp@avp-xub11:~$
```

показывает информацию о текущем пользователе и группах, в которые он входит.

Например, команда `tail` читает несколько последних строк файла. Если ее запустит syslog или avp (он входит в группу adm), то команда отработает, а если кто-то другой, не входящий в группу adm (как видите это группа, приписанная к файлу. При создании файла берется первичная группа пользователя, который создает файл, но потом ее можно изменить), то мы увидим -- `/var/log/syslog: Permission denied`.

Вот вкратце и все. Если будут конкретные вопросы -- задавайте.

Comment: Премного благодарен!
Прямым образом это не отвечает на вопрос, но изложение и информативность в полной мере поспособствовали решению задачи. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В общем в nix'ах в таких случаях принято создавать группу и добавить в нее обоих пользователей.

Вообще вот: https://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine

Достаточно подробно описано. Будут вопросы, пишите.

Comment: Спасибо, друг, но я мало что понял. Новичок-с.
Как создание группы может решить проблему, если по логике надо её не просто создать, а наделить правами? Может проще как-то скрипт запускать от имени другого пользователя? Запутался я.